# Continuity of branch of logarithm to the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Let $H_{0}=\{s\in\mathbb{C} : \Re(s)>0\}$ and $H_{1}=\{s\in\mathbb{C} : \Re(s)>1\}$. Assume that $f:H_{0}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic on $H_{0}$ and doesn't vanish on $H_1$. Then we know that there exists a branch of the logarithm of $f$ on $H_{1}$, i.e. a holomorphic function $g:H_{1}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\exp(g(s))=f(s)$ for all $s\in H_{1}$.

Now assume that we also know that $f(1)\neq 0$. Since $\Re(g(s))=\log(\vert f(s)\vert)$ for all $s\in H_1$, where $\log$ denotes the real logarithm, we know in particular that the limit as $s\in\mathbb{R}$ tends to $1$ from above, $\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{+}}\Re(g(s))$, exists.

Does the fact that $f$ is holomorphic on $H_0$ imply that actually the limit $\lim_{s\rightarrow 1^{+}}g(s)$ exists?

Comment: that's obvious since $f(1) \ne 0$ means that there is a holomorphic logarithm in a neighborhood of $1$, call it $g_1$; but $g_1-g$ is constant on a small open set to the right of $1$ so adjusting it to make the constant zero, $g_1$ gives an analytic extension of $g$ to the left of $1$ - note this doesn't imply that one can extend $g$ on a half-plane to the left of $1$ just in a small neighborhood of $1$; if we would know that $f$ doesn't vanish on the whole line $\Re s=1$ we could extend to an open neighborhood of it to the left but it may be asymptotic to $\Re s=1$ so not contain a line

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed obvious!

Comment: happy to be of help